# An algorithm to find the seed root of a given number

Tags: algorithm

I came across this question at [Glassdoor](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Epic-Interview-Questions-E35163.htm) and tried to implement it.The question is as follows-

> Consider a number 123, the product of the number with its digits (123*1*2*3 = 738) is 738. Therefore, 123 is the seed root of 738. Write a program to accept a number and find all possible seed roots. For example, If the user entered 4977 then the answer should be 79 and 711.

I thought of one way:

1. Find all the digits from 2 to 9 which divide the number.
2. Then start from the biggest digit (among the digits found in step 1) and find the numbers that make up the number and then print all the permutations of those numbers.

But, this assumes that the digits are not repeated and secondly it doesn't print all the numbers like for 4977 it can find 79 but will not find 711.

Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

My approach would be something like this.  It's a recursive algorithm that uses a set S which is a multiset containing digits from 2 to 9, possibly multiple times.

```
try (N, S, digit) {
    for d = digit, digit-1, ..., 2 {
        if N is divisible by d then {
            S' = S + {d};
            if N/d is composed of all the digits in S', perhaps with
               some 1's thrown in, then N/d is an answer;
            try (N/d, S', d);
        }
    }
}
```

then for the original number

```
try (originalN, empty-set, 9);
also check originalN to see if it has only 1 digits (11, 11111, etc.); if so, then it's also an answer
```

I think this will work, but I may have missed some boundary cases.

For 4977, `try(4977, empty, 9)` will find that 4977 is divisible by 9, so it calls `try(553, {9}, 9)`.  The inner `try` finds 553 is divisible by 7, and 553/7 = 79; at that point S' = {7, 9} and the algorithm checks to see if 79 is composed of the digits {7, 9}, which succeeds.  The algorithm keeps going, though.  Eventually we'll backtrack to the outer `try`, which will at some point try `d = 7`, and 4977/7 = 711, and when we do the check, S' = {7} and 711 is composed of 7 with some 1's, so that's also an answer.

EDIT: I've included a complete C++ function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct digitMultiset {
    int counts[10];  // note: the [0] and [1] elements are not used
};

static const digitMultiset empty = { {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

bool hasDigits (const int n, digitMultiset& s) {
    digitMultiset s2 = empty;
    int temp = n;
    int digit;
    while (temp > 0) {
        digit = temp % 10;
        if (digit == 0) return false;
        if (digit != 1) s2.counts[digit]++;
        temp /= 10;
    }
    for (int d = 2; d < 10; d++)
        if (s2.counts[d] != s.counts[d]) return false;
    return true;
}

void tryIt (const int currval, const digitMultiset& s,
            const int digit, vector<int>& answers) {
    digitMultiset newS;
    for (int d = digit; d >= 2; d--) {
        if (currval % d == 0) {
            int quotient = currval / d;
            newS = s;
            newS.counts[d]++;
            if (hasDigits (quotient, newS))
                answers.push_back (quotient);
            tryIt (quotient, newS, d, answers);
        }
    }
}

void seedProduct (const int val) {
    vector<int> answers;
    tryIt (val, empty, 9, answers);
    int temp = val;
    bool allOnes = true;
    while (temp > 0)  {
        if (temp % 10 != 1) {
            allOnes = false;
            break;
        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
    if (allOnes)
        answers.push_back(val);

    int count = answers.size();
    if (count > 0)  {
        if (count == 1)
            cout << val << " has seed product " << answers[0] << endl;
        else  {
            cout << val << " has " << count << " seed products: ";
            for (int& ans : answers)
                cout << ans << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how you thought it,but it seems to work.Let others have a review

Comment: Notice you don't quit recursing if you find an answer. You only quit recursing if you find an N that isn't divisible by any digits except 1.

Comment: Right, it may return multiple answers, which was part of the requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to check every divisor of n and see if this could be a seed. To check all the divisors, you just need to check to the square root of n. So this algorithm runs in O(sqrt(n)). Could you do it faster?

Here is a simple C++ programme demonstrating this idea.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int prod(int n){
  int res=n;
  while(n!=0){
    res*=n%10;
    n/=10;
  }
  return res;
}

int main(){
  int n;
  cin >> n;

  for(int i=1;i*i<=n;++i){
    if(n%i==0){
      if(prod(i)==n)
        cout << i << endl;
      if(n/i!=i && prod(n/i)==n)
        cout << n/i << endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The result I'm seeing is that my algorithm is a lot faster when there are no answers, if the number is greater than 25000 or so.  It's about 2x faster for 6-digit numbers, 4x for 7 digits.  When there is at least one answer, your algorithm is about 2x faster for seven-digit numbers, and the ratio is greater for smaller numbers.  I'm finding that about 99% or more of values have no solution; so for a program that loops through all possible input values in some range, if it involves 5-digit or larger numbers, mine should be a lot faster.

Comment: Well, if on want to loop through all possible values in some (1 to n) range, something like `for(n in range) resultat[prod(n)].push_back(n)` may be much faster.

Comment: +1 Indeed the simplest solution to understand. Thanks! @Blabla404

Answer (score 0):

First, Find all the ways to factor the number:

100 
 - 2 * 50
 - 4 * 25
 - 2 * 2 * 25
 - ... and so forth ...
 - 2 * 2 * 5 * 5

If there are any 1 digits in the number, add some factors using those:

- 1 * 2 * 50
- 1 * 4 * 25
- ... and so on

Run through all those factorizations and see if any of are of the right form.

The "right form" is a factorization that has one factor that has the same number of digits as the count of factors (less one) and those other factors equal the digits

This suggests a way to filter the factorizations as you find them because once you find

- two double-digit or higher factors (since a solution consts of one factor the may have more than one digit plus all other factors having exactly one digit) -OR-
- more single-digit factors than the number of digits in the original number (since a factor can never have more digits than the original number)
- there are probably more

that factorization can't work.

Here is a link to some ways to factorize a number: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.117.1230&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Here's some code that does this. No promise about correct in all cases. Uses brute force to factorize and a few filters to short-circuit the process when it can't work out.

```java
package com.x.factors;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Factors {

    private List<Long> solutions;
    private final long original;
    private final int originalDigitCount;
    private List<Long> primes = new ArrayList<Long>();

    public Factors(long original) {
        this.original = original;
        this.originalDigitCount = ("" + original).length();
    }

    public List<Long> findSeeds() {
        // Consider a number 123, the product of the number with its digits (123*1*2*3 = 738) is 738. Therefore, 123 is
        // the seed product of 738. Write a program to accept a number and find all possible seed products. For example,
        // If the user entered 4977 then the answer should be 79 and 711.

        solutions = new ArrayList<Long>();

        // filter out numbers that can't have seeds

        // Number must be positive (and not zero)
        if (original <= 0) {
            return solutions;
        }

        // Find a number with a 0 digit in it
        long temp = original;
        while (temp > 0) {
            if (temp % 10 == 0) {
                return solutions;
            }
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        collectFactors(original, new ArrayList<Long>(), 0, 0);

        return solutions;
    }

    private void collectFactors(long num, List<Long> factors, int factorCount, int doubleDigitFactorCount) {
        if (primes.contains(num)) {
            return;
        }

        // The seed can't have more digits than the original number. Thus if we find more factors excluding
        // the seed than that, this can't be a solution.
        if (factorCount > originalDigitCount) {
            return;
        }

        boolean isPrime = true; // check whether num is prime
        int newDoubleDigitFactorCount = 0;
        for (long i = num / 2; i > 1; --i) {

            // Once we have one factor 2 digits or over, it has to be the seed, so there is no use trying
            // any more double digit numbers as only single digits are needed.
            if (i > 9) {
                if (doubleDigitFactorCount > 0) {
                    return; // short circuit because of two many non-one-digit factors
                }
                newDoubleDigitFactorCount = 1;
            } else {
                newDoubleDigitFactorCount = 0;
            }

            long remdr = num / i;
            if (remdr * i == num) { // is it a factor?
                isPrime = false; // it has a factor, its not prime

                // add this new factor into the list
                if (factors.size() <= factorCount) {
                    factors.add(i);
                } else {
                    factors.set(factorCount, i);
                }

                // found a list of factors ... add in the remainder and evaluate
                if (factors.size() <= factorCount + 1) {
                    factors.add(remdr);
                } else {
                    factors.set(factorCount + 1, remdr);
                }
                long seed = evaluate(factors, factorCount + 2);
                if (seed > 0) {
                    if (solutions.contains(seed)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    solutions.add(seed);
                }

                collectFactors(remdr, factors, factorCount + 1, doubleDigitFactorCount + newDoubleDigitFactorCount);
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) { // if its prime, save it
            primes.add(num);
        }
        return;
    }

    /* package */long evaluate(List<Long> factors, int factorCount) {
        // Find seed, the largest factor (or one of them if several are the same)
        long seed = 0; // Note seed will be larger than 0
        int seedIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < factorCount; ++i) {
            if (factors.get(i) > seed) {
                seed = factors.get(i);
                seedIndex = i;
            }
        }

        // Count the digits in the seed, see if there are the right number of factors. Ignore 1's
        boolean[] factorUsed = new boolean[factorCount]; // start off as all false
        int seedDigitCount = 0;
        long temp = seed;
        while (temp > 0) {
            if (temp % 10 != 1) {
                ++seedDigitCount;
            }
            temp = temp / 10;
        }
        if (seedDigitCount != factorCount - 1) {
            return 0; // fail - seed digit count doesn't equal number of single digit factors
        }

        // See if all the seed's digits are present
        temp = seed;
        factorUsed[seedIndex] = true;
        while (temp > 0) {
            int digit = (int) (temp % 10);
            if (digit != 1) { // 1's are never in the factor array, they are just freely ok
                boolean digitFound = false;
                for (int digitIndex = 0; digitIndex < factorCount; ++digitIndex) {
                    if (digit == factors.get(digitIndex) && !factorUsed[digitIndex]) {
                        factorUsed[digitIndex] = true;
                        digitFound = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!digitFound) {
                    return 0; // fail, a digit in the seed isn't in the other factors
                }
            }
            temp = temp / 10;
        }

        // At this point we know there are the right number of digits in the seed AND we have
        // found all the seed digits in the list of factors
        return seed;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Run through all those factorizations" could take a while, unless you have some idea to improve it...

Comment: @Lee Meador:Dukeling is right.Also if you have a number say `81` then you can write it as `9*9` ,`3*3*9`,`3*3*3*3`.All of them being 1 digits.How will we handle such cases?

Comment: All but one of those wouldn't be "in the right form". You'll have to write code to detect a factorization that has one factor that has the same number of digits as the count of factors (less one) and those other factors equal the digits. 9 * 9 meets that criteria. 9 is the number and the list of digits is [9] a list of length 1.

Comment: Note that finding all the factorizations is an arbitrarily hard problem. For example, the simpleminded way to do it is to iterate over all integers up to 1/2 the number, check whether that integer is a factor and if so recurse to find factors of the original number divided by the factor. That would take a long time for a 100 digit number.

Comment: Been fooling with it. Try 497745674 which has no seeds but takes me about 10 seconds to find that. Or try 9333333 which has one seed with a lot of 1s in it. (@ajb probably has a faster algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple program.  Under 1 second to get the seed root of `176852740608`. [Live demo](http://ideone.com/k2CIcM).

*Update: It takes 27 seconds to find 376,352,349 -> 153,642,082,955,760 .  What about you guys?  I have no idea if that's good or not.*

*Update2:  @ajb has a faster answer, at least on the experiments I did.  But this answer has the advantage of being simpler!*

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int Big_Int; // To get a 64-bit int

void root_stem(const Big_Int r, const Big_Int product_of_my_digits, const Big_Int target) {

        // There are two rules we can use to prune:
        //
        // First: The product_of_my_digits must divide into the target.
        //        If not, return
        // Second: The products produced lower in the search true will always be higher
        //         than those above. Therefore, we should return early if
        //         my_seed_product is larger than the target

        if (target % product_of_my_digits != 0)
                return;

        Big_Int my_seed_product = r * product_of_my_digits;

        if(my_seed_product >= target) {
                if (my_seed_product == target) {
                        cout << r << "\t->\t" << my_seed_product << endl;
                }
                return;
        }
        // print all roots, with their products, between 10*r and 10*r + 9
        for(Big_Int digit_to_append = 1; digit_to_append<=9; ++digit_to_append) {
                root_stem(r*10 + digit_to_append, product_of_my_digits*digit_to_append, target);
        }
}

int main() {
        root_stem(0,1, 4977);
        root_stem(0,1, 24562368);
        root_stem(0,1, 176852740608);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Less than 1 second for 176852740608. Find all the factors then check whether a particular factor is seed root or not.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Number {
    long value;
    public ArrayList<Long> factors= new ArrayList<Long>();

    public Number(long a){
        value = a;
        for(long i=1;i<= Math.sqrt(a);i++){
            if(a%i==0)
                {
                factors.add(i);
                if((a/i)!=i)
                    factors.add(a/i);
                }
        }
        System.out.println(factors);
    }


public static void main(String args[]){
    long x = 24562368L;
    Number N = new Number(x);
    for(long i : N.factors){
        long ProductOfDigits = 1;
        long k = i;
        while(k!=0){
            ProductOfDigits = ProductOfDigits*(k%10);
            k = k/10;
        }
        if(i*ProductOfDigits == N.value)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Seeds
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
             int num=4977;
             if(!seed(num).isEmpty())
                 System.out.println(seed(num));
             else
                 System.out.println("no seed number");
        }
        public static List<Integer> seed(int num)
        {  List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=1; i<=num; i++)
                {
                if(num%i==0)
                {
                    int factor_digit=1;
                    int factor = i;
                    factor_digit=factor_digit*factor;

            // when i is the factor, find factors of i and multiply them together to form number        
            while(factor>=1)
            {
                factor_digit = factor_digit * (factor%10); 
                factor = factor/10;     
            }
            if(factor_digit== num) 
                list.add(i);
        }

    }
            return list;
    }
    }

*
```

Answer (score 0):

> Implement a program to find out whether a number is a seed of another number.
> A number X is said to be a seed of number Y if multiplying X by its every digit equates to Y.
> E.g.: 123 is a seed of 738 as 123*1*2*3 = 738 */

```
class SeedNumber 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int seed = 45;
        int num = 900;
        int seedNum = seed;
        int check=1;
        for(check=check*seed;seed>0;seed /=10)
        {
            int rem = seed % 10;
            check = check * rem;              
        }
        System.out.println(check);
        if(check == num)
            System.out.println(seedNum+" is a seed of "+num);
        else
            System.out.println(seedNum+" is not a seed of "+num);
        // Implement your code here 
    }
}
```